# IMAP is not working in PHP

Tags: php, imap

The following code is not working. I get this error: `500 - Internal server error :: Warning: imap_open() [function.imap-open]: Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX`

Here is the code:

```
$hostname = 'xxxx';
$username = 'xxxx';
$password = 'xxxx';

$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');
if($emails) 
{
    $output = '';
    rsort($emails);
    foreach($emails as $email_number) 
    {
        $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
        $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);

        $output.= '<div class="toggler '.($overview[0]->seen ? 'read' : 'unread').'">';
        $output.= '<span class="subject">'.$overview[0]->subject.'</span> ';
        $output.= '<span class="from">'.$overview[0]->from.'</span>';
        $output.= '<span class="date">on '.$overview[0]->date.'</span>';
        $output.= '</div>';


        $output.= '<div class="body">'.$message.'</div>';
    }
    echo $output;
} 

imap_close($inbox);
```

Comment: What is the error? What exactly are you asking for help with?

Comment: It Is Showing 500 - Internal server error.

Comment: have you tried enabling error reporting so you can see the actualy error description?

Comment: The Error Is ::
Warning: imap_open() [function.imap-open]: Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX in

Comment: Can you reach imap.gmail.com:993 directly from the server this script is running on?  If not, you're probably dealing with a firewall.

Comment: The inbox in Gmail is called `[Gmail]`, not `INBOX`.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested and was able to get that exact error.  To fix it, I did this:

1) Turned on IMAP in Google
2) Entered in the correct login credentials.

I believe it was triggered by incorrect login credentials.  Also, it appears you can't use prefixes like "recent:" in front of the username.