# php - imap_open producing 500 Internal Server Error & no fcgid.conf file in /etc/httpd/conf.d/ folder

Tags: php, apache

I am using the following script to access my gmail from php called `this.php`

I have regered to [IMAP is not working in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12037862/imap-is-not-working-in-php) as well as [Imap error on myname@mydomain.com but working on myname@gmail.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15804428/imap-error-on-mynamemydomain-com-but-working-on-mynamegmail-com)

I have confirmed that opensll and imap extensions are loaded into Apache.

I have confirmed file permission on the file

In apache logs the only error I get is

```
[Tue Jun 17 23:42:12 2014] [warn] [client 24.120.116.118] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 40 seconds
[Tue Jun 17 23:42:12 2014] [error] [client 24.120.116.118] Premature end of script headers: this.php
[Tue Jun 17 23:42:12 2014] [error] [client 24.120.116.118] File does not exist: /home/cesarbi1/public_html/500.shtml
```

No matter what I get a 500. If I comment out the line with `imap_open` then the page does not 500.

Is there somewhere else I can look for errors? or can someone tell me whats wrong with my script?

```
<?php
/* connect to gmail */
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'username@gmail.com';
$password = 'password';

/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to your email account: ' . imap_last_error());

/* grab emails */
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'UNSEEN') or die('Cannot connect to your email account: ' . imap_last_error());

/* if emails are returned, cycle through each... */
if($emails) {

    /* begin output var */
    $output = '';

    /* put the newest emails on top */
    rsort($emails);

    /* for every email... */
    foreach($emails as $email_number) {

        /* get information specific to this email */
        $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
        $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);

        /* output the email header information */
        $output.= '<div class="toggler '.($overview[0]->seen ? 'read' : 'unread').'">';
        $output.= '<span class="subject">'.$overview[0]->subject.'</span> ';
        $output.= '<span class="from">'.$overview[0]->from.'</span>';
        $output.= '<span class="date">on '.$overview[0]->date.'</span>';
        $output.= '</div>';

        /* output the email body */
        $output.= '<div class="body">'.$message.'</div>';
    }

    echo $output;
} 

/* close the connection */
imap_close($inbox);
?>
```

**SOLVED UPDATE**

While this question is of the same nature of the other question, the other one does not provide a solution for those of us without `fcgid.conf` located in the `/etc/httpd/conf.d/` folder. I am also editing my title to be more specific to the error.

I fixed my issue by adding at the end of my file httpd.conf

```
Include "/etc/httpd/conf.d/cfgid.conf"
```

and then I manually created the file in

```
/etc/httpd/conf.d/fcgid.conf
```

and added the following code which worked.

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    FcgidIdleTimeout 3600
    FcgidProcessLifeTime 3600
    FcgidIOTimeout 3600
    FcgidBusyTimeout 3600
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Sounds like firewall to me..

Comment: @Eric Just checked and that is a negative

Comment: While it is a similar question the solutions are very different as I explained in my update

Answer (score 0):

Your errors are this:

```
[Tue Jun 17 23:42:12 2014] [warn] [client 24.120.116.118] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 40 seconds
[Tue Jun 17 23:42:12 2014] [error] [client 24.120.116.118] Premature end of script headers: this.php
[Tue Jun 17 23:42:12 2014] [error] [client 24.120.116.118] File does not exist: /home/cesarbi1/public_html/500.shtml
```

Seems to me that the error is in the first line:

```
mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 40 seconds
```

Looking at your script you are connecting via IMAP & then outputting directly to your browser (I assume) while e-mails are being read? Well, if you have a moderately sized e-mail box, that 40 seconds would be eaten up pretty quickly.

So you might have to go into your `FastCGI` config here; assuming you are on a Linux setup:

```
/etc/httpd/conf.d/fcgid.conf
```

And edit this line to be something like:

```
FcgidIOTimeout 120
```

Which equates to two minutes. Which is still way to high for a practical web server application, but should work to solve this issue.  Just change that line, restart Apache & test it again. If you are on Ubuntu you would restart Apache like this:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: I have a VPS Bluehost account and support seemed to have no idea how to fix this for me. There is no `/etc/httpd/conf.d/fcgid.conf` file in that directory and even if I create it, still nothing. My server is a `CENTOS 6.5 x86_64 kvm – server`

Comment: Here is a link to an output of `grep -R "FcgidIOTimeout" /etc/httpd` please tell me where it is https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2659865/FcgidIOTimeout-output.txt

Comment: I said I did `grep -R "FcgidIOTimeout" /etc/httpd`

Comment: Sorry about the response, I got frustrated...sorry bro